# Preserving a value between functions using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am writing a jQuery plugin and am running into a few problems with regard to variables. For example I have the following skeleton structure for my plugin, which is going to act on a textbox. In my init function I want to set a variable and bind a keypress event to my textbox. That keypress event needs to call another function, in which I need the variable. Is this possible?

```
(function($){
    var methods = {
        init : function(options){
            return this.each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var someVar = 'somevar';
                $this.keypress(function(event){
                    //I want to call my customFunction
                });
            });
        },
        customFunction : function(){
            //I am wanting to access 'someVar' here
        };
    $.fn.mynamespace = function(method){
        //handle which method to call here
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `myVar` in an outer scope, and the fact that functions in JavaScript may be [closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) will allow what you want to work:

```
(function($){
    var someVar;
    var methods = {
        init : function(options){
            return this.each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                someVar = 'somevar';
                $this.keypress(function(event){
                    //I want to call my customFunction
                });
            });
        },
        customFunction : function(){
            //You may access 'someVar' here
        };
    $.fn.mynamespace = function(method){
        //handle which method to call here
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**Edit**: However, if you want to store data specific to each HTML element, you should use the [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method of jQuery objects, or [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) for the element itself. For example:

```
(function($){
    var someVar;
    var methods = {
        init : function(options){
            return this.each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.data('myCode.blargle','somevar');
                $this.keypress(function(event){
                    //I want to call my customFunction
                });
            });
        },
        customFunction : function(){
          var someVar = $(this).data('myCode.blargle');
          // or $.data(this,'myCode.blargle');
        };
    $.fn.mynamespace = function(method){
        //handle which method to call here
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I thought of doing that. Say for instance var someVar is a concatenation of the chars entered in the textbox. Now if I have two textboxes using this plugin then someVar will be a concatenation of both textboxes. i.e. This only works if I have one textbox using the plugin. Am I calling the function correctly: $this.mynamespace('customFunction')?